# Value restriction when there are no generic parameters

Tags: f#, value-restriction

I get the value restriction error on `let makeElem` in the following code:

```
let elemCreator (doc: XmlDocument) = 
    fun name (value: obj) ->
        let elem = doc.CreateElement(name)
        match value with
        | :? seq<#XmlNode> as childs -> 
            childs |> Seq.iter (fun c -> elem.AppendChild(c) |> ignore)
            elem
        | _ -> elem.Value <- value.ToString(); elem

let doc = new XmlDocument()
let makeElem = elemCreator doc
```

Why I get the value restriction error if anonymous function returned from `elemCreator` hasn't any generic parameters?

The compiler states that the infered type of makeElem is `(string -> 'a -> XmlNode)`. But why it infers second parameter as `'a` if I've declared it as `obj`?

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* that this may be the "expected" behavior (although unfortunate in this case), as a result of the compiler's generalization and condensation processes.  Consider Tomas's example:

```
let foo (s:string) (a:obj) = a
```

If you were to define

```
let bar a = foo "test" a
```

then the compiler will infer the type `bar : 'a -> obj` because it generalizes the type of the first argument.  In your case, you have the equivalent of

```
let bar = foo "test"
```

so `bar` is a value rather than a syntactic function.  The compiler does essentially the same inference procedure, except now the value restriction applies.  This is unfortunate in your case, since it means that you have to explicitly annotate `makeElem` with a type annotation (or make it a syntactic function).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an unexpected behavior to me. It can be demonstrated using a simpler function:

```
let foo (s:string) (a:obj) = a
let bar = foo "bar"             // Value restriction
```

One possible explanation might be that the F# compiler allows you to call a function taking parameter of some type with an argument of any subtype. So, you can call `foo "hi" (new A())` without explicitly casting `A` to `obj` (which used to be required some time ago).

This implicit casting could mean that the compiler actually interprets `bar` as something like this:

```
let bar a = foo "bar" (a :> obj)
```

...and so it thinks that the argument is generic. Anyway, this is just a speculation, so you could try sending this as a bug report to *fsbugs* at *microsoft* dot *com*.

Comment: I've just sent bug request at fsbugs, thanks for the proposal! I'll let you know if they give me reply.

Comment: I think this has to do with `obj` specifically and not polymorphism in general. I don't see how this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

(The following is based solely on observation.)

If you have a function `obj -> 'a`, calls to that function are not used to infer/solve the type of its argument. An illustration:

```
let writeLine (arg: obj) = System.Console.WriteLine(arg)
```

`writeLine` is `obj -> unit`

```
let square x = 
  writeLine x
  x * x
```

In the above function `x` is inferred as `int` because of `(*)`. If a type could be constrained by `obj` then this function would not work (`x` would be inferred as `obj` prior to the use of `(*)`, which would cause an error along the lines of: *type `obj` does not support operator `(*)`*).

I think this behavior is a Good Thing. There's no need to restrict a type as `obj` because every type is already implicitly convertible to `obj`. This allows your program to be more generic and provides better interoperability with the .NET BCL.

In short, `obj` has no bearing on type inference (yay!).